# how can I display my array data into textboxes?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

Here's the scenario, I have here my array from my sqlite db then I already converted it into array, now I need to display every element into textbox. Can someone help me, please? Thank you! Btw it's flask/python.

Javascript :

```js
$(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        liveClock();
        loadNewDecimal();
    }, 1000);

    function loadNewDecimal() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/update_decimal",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                arr = data.row1 + ''
                conv_arr = arr.split("-")
                //console.log(conv_arr)
            }
        });
    };
}
```

---

HTML :

```html
</div>
   <form class="form-inline text-center justify-content-center">
      <form class="form-inline text-center justify-content-center">
          {% for row1 in rows %} <input class="form-control col-md-1 mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="Cell1" placeholder="Cell1" readonly type="text" value="{{row1["> {% endfor %}
      </form>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just display it as JSON

`JSON.stringfig(arr)`

Comment: Now it is in JSON format, but how can I display my 10 array elements into 10 textboxes?

Comment: Is there a problem with just putting it there? It's all strings

Comment: I mean it's okay but how can I loop it to display every element inside a textbox? Sorry, I'm not quite good at this, but thanks a lot!